# ep_page_view plugin etherpad: how to disable it?

Tags: plugins, etherpad

I am using ep_page_view plugin for etherpad. As per described here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_page_view

I want to turn off page view in my etherpad. I tried to add following lines combination in my settings.json file but none of these worked:

```
1.    "ep_page_view_disable_change" : false,
      "ep_page_view_default" : false,

2.    "ep_page_view_default" : false,

3.    "ep_page_view_disable_change" : true,
      "ep_page_view_default" : false,
```

I am not initializing the pad by giving parameter: &pageview=true as prescribed.
Still the page break is appearing in my pad.

Any idea how to turn this page break functionality off without uninstalling the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what was the problem but adding following lines in middle of settings.json instead of in last worked:

```
 "ep_page_view_disable_change" : true,
  "ep_page_view_default" : false,
```

And i also restarted the bin/sh from terminal .